# How can I find index of rows just same as a array from a pandas dataframe?

Tags: pandas, dataframe, indexing

I want to find indexes of some rows same as a array from pandas dataframe.

My dataframe is like below

`df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[True, False, True, True],'b':[False, True, True, True],'c':[True, True, False, True],'d':[True, False, True, False]})`

the input value that I'll enter is like 
`row = [True, True, False, True]`, and I want get `[2]`.

I tried some with for like this

```
index = []
for i in range df.shape[0]:
    if df.iloc[i,:].tolist() == row
        index.append(i)
```

It works but extremely slow for my work. Is there any method for this?

Answer (score 4):

Use [`DataFrame.eq`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.eq.html) and [`Series.all`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.all.html):

```
df[df.eq(row).all(1)]
```

---

#### Example

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[True, False, True, True],'b':[False, True, True, True],'c':[True, True, False, True],'d':[True, False, True, False]})
row = [True, True, False, True]

df[df.eq(row).all(1)]
```

[out]

```
      a     b      c     d
2  True  True  False  True
```

---

If needed, chain on [`index.to_list()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.tolist.html) for list of indices:

```
df[df.eq(row).all(1)].index.to_list()

[2]
```

Comment: @Luterino no problem buddy, glad it helps